# Why does 電池 take the を particle

Tags: grammar, particle-を, transitivity, object

The sentence

咲は電池{でんち}を時計｛とけい｝に入｛はい｝れました。

Translates as "Saki put the batteries in the watch" but would would 電池 take を in this case?

Comment: The last word should be いれました, not はいれました. Is that what is causing the confusion?

Comment: Question to you. If you do not like wo, then what particle do you consider by yourself?

Comment: Just for your consideration: adventures of [wo] vs [ga] in contemporary Japanese language https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69221/

Answer (score 6):

> 咲【さき】は電池{でんち}を時計｛とけい｝に入｛い｝れました。

As noted in the comments, the verb in your sample sentence is 入【い】れます・入【い】れる, not 入【はい】ります・入【はい】る.  The former with れ is the transitive form meaning *"to put something into something else"*, whereas the latter with り or る is the intransitive form meaning *"to enter into something"*.  Since the verb in your sample sentence is transitive, it takes an object, and Japanese grammar requires that the object is marked with the を particle.